# I am trying to use a java record keeping project, but the program cannot seem to connect to the database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, netbeans-platform

I have a simple library record keeping project i want to use, it is based on GUI & adds library book records, library members, books borrowed, etc.

It is implied the project uses DB, i.e. Mysql, however when i am trying to store a record into the DB the failed option executes, as in the record is not being able to be saved in the DB by the project.

The code is in modules so :

**Code for establishing the connections**

```
     import java.sql.Connection;
     import java.sql.DriverManager;

     public class DB {
       public static Connection getConnection(){
       Connection con=null;
       try{
           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
           con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","","");
          }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
          return con;
         }

       }
```

**Code for getting the records:**

```
     import java.sql.*;
      public class LibrarianDao {


         public static int save(String name,String password,String email,String address,String city,String contact){
         int status=0;
         try{
        Connection con=DB.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into 
        librarian(name,password,email,address,city,contact) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        ps.setString(1,name);
        ps.setString(2,password);
        ps.setString(3,email);
        ps.setString(4,address);
        ps.setString(5,city);
        ps.setString(6,contact);
        status=ps.executeUpdate();
        con.close();
    }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
    return status;
}
public static int delete(int id){
    int status=0;
    try{
        Connection con=DB.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("delete from librarian where id=?");
        ps.setInt(1,id);
        status=ps.executeUpdate();
        con.close();
    }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
    return status;
    }

    public static boolean validate(String name,String password){
       boolean status=false;
       try{
        Connection con=DB.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from librarian where name=? and password=?");
        ps.setString(1,name);
        ps.setString(2,password);
        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
        status=rs.next();
        con.close();
    }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
    return status;
   }

  }
```

Obvoiusly there are other code modules that interact with the DB as well, the project has a dedicated folder for all class files & similar for all ".java" files it is executed via a ".jar" file, but i do not know where to add the java-Mysql connector in the project folder, so it can access the DB.

MY queries are:

1) where in the project folder should i add the mysql connector to allow access to the mysql DB.

2) Any adding of the connector to the project has to be done manually (normally) or via netbeans.

3) if it has to be done via netbeans how do i recreate a new .jar file to execute the project.

Comment: Wait is any kind of exception being thrown? Try e.printStackTrace() instead of System.out.println(e).

Comment: yes well i am connecting to the DB via a defined environment variable pointing to the jdbc connector . jar file before compiling & executing the program, so the excpetion being thrown is: Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdb
c.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class
 is generally unnecessary.
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: CLIENT_PLUGIN_AUTH is required
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: i have rewritten the DB url as: con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javabase","java","password");

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you're closing the connection before closing the prepared statement. Make sure you close the prepared statement as well. Use a try-with-resources for both the connection and prepared statement if possible.

Another possible problem is you're not providing credentials when creating the connection. Does your MySQL DB not require user and pass auth?

Comment: yes well i am connecting to the DB via a defined environment variable pointing to the jdbc connector . jar file before compiling & executing the program, so the excpetion being thrown is: Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdb
c.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class
 is generally unnecessary.
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: CLIENT_PLUGIN_AUTH is required
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: i have rewritten the DB url as: con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javabase","java","password");

Comment: It sounds like you need to change the driver class to something not deprecated

Comment: my sql version is 5x & connector is 8.0.18, could that be the reason for the disparity in the class def ??, would downloading a more current version of Mysql be helpful ?

Comment: If it's below 5.6 then yes you need to upgrade MySQL or downgrade connector.